# Getting wrong value from adaptive cards with input.date in MS Teams

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, azure-node-sdk

We have created an adaptive card with Input.Date field for MS Teams using botframework(in node). I have a dialog where the user choose date from date picker. But when user select date from date picker it gives date from input.date filed as one day before.
for ex: if we choose 10/12/2021 from date picker, it gives date value as 09/12/2021.
[Date Picker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCJ84.png)

From Date picker image, I selected date as 12/10/2021 from date picker. but getting date value as 12/09/2021 from teams bot channel. Please find date value in below image(Date value(response) from teams channel).
[Date value(response) from teams channel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyDec.png)

Comment: We have a bug raised for it already. We will update you.

Comment: Has there been any update on this bug? I am also currently expirencing this issue.

Comment: Team is working on the fix. We do not have any ETA to share

Comment: This issue has been fixed. We have checked and its working fine.